# Error block not working in Sinatra app

Tags: sinatra

I have the following Sinatra app and I am testing the `error` block but it doesnt seem to be working.

Here's my sinatra app:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

error do
  puts "----> Failed"
  $stdout.print "----> Failed"
end

get "/*" do
  raise "Error!!"
end
```

I am using sinatra (1.3.3)

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" isn't a very good description of your problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can add:

```
set :show_exceptions, false
```

To your application file.

In development environments `show_exceptions` is enabled by default.

Answer (score 4):

Sinatra uses its own error handler when it is set in `development` mode, which it is by default. For your error to show up you have to run your app in `production` mode like this:

```
ruby my_app.rb -e production
```

Here's a link to the specific documentation for further reference:
[Sinatra README #Environments](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Environments)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are not using the beta version of rack

```
gem list rack
```

if you see something like the following:

```
rack-1.6.0.beta
```

Uninstall this version and use the previous version rack-1.5.2